# Reusing One UITableView for Directory Listing Application

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hello fellow StackOverflowers, I am in a bit of a dilemma with trying to condense the code in my application, iEngineering, that is available for free on the AppStore. Please download it so you can follow along with the rest of this post.

Alright, so when creating the current version of iEngineering, I used a new UIViewController with a UITableView for every "new" screen for all of the listing (table view) screens. The one story board file I am using currently has ~100 view controllers, takes 10 minutes to load, and several minutes to load the simulator. Big, big rookie mistake.

I am currently in progress in developing a plan to condense all of the UITableViewControllers into a single reusuable UITableViewController if it's feasible. However, I am running into trouble in figuring out what topics I should research to learn out how to refresh/present an updated listing (table view) in the view controller if you segue/transition to a subdirectory screen of the app. For example, selecting "Chemical Engineering" in the home screen and transitioning to the next listing screen that displays the following: "General Chemistry, Fluid Mechanics, Reactor Design, Separations, and Thermodynamics."

Would this be a reasonable/feasible task to condense down my current project? If so, what topics should I research to figure out how to do the transitioning/updating to a new table view screen?

In the images below, I am trying to condense the view controllers into only a couple of view controllers (Note: The image doesnt display the 80+ view controllers off the screen. xCode wouldn't zoom out anymore.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Even if you are using a single `ViewController` class for handling any kind of listing, you will create another instance of that class when presenting sub-category listing so there is no point of refreshing/reloading the same `tableView`.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but FWIW, separating major sections of your app into separate storyboards can also prevent situations like these on larger projects.

Comment: I have thought about this but I wasnt sure if that would be the best way to go. I will look into into it. This project is going to be very large scale. Thank you all.

Comment: For example, would xCode experience any loading problems if I have 100+ storyboard files and within each storyboard file I have around ~10 view controllers?